# Modeling GraphQL mutations

Tags: api, graphql, schema, bookmarks, mutation

I have come across a problem with modeling mutations in GraphQL and am trying to figure out the right approach (for my use cases, of course). Let's say we have this example simple schema (referring to Bookmarks on a web):

```
type Bookmark {
 name: String!
 owner: String
 description: String
 createdAt: String
}

input BookmarkInput {
 name: String
 description: String
}

type Query {
 getBookmarks: [Bookmark]
}

type Mutation {
 updateBookmark(input: BookmarkInput): Bookmark
}
```

In this case, in the mutation for example I gave only the action to edit a given Bookmark. The problem arises when we want to make an inline attribute update, and some attributes are unchangeable, or worse, some attributes will be required even though we do not want to change them right now. In this case, I have to work out an approach. In this case we have a lot of simple fields that are easy to edit, expand or change later. An example mutation could then look like this:

```
input BookmarkUpdateAction {
 updateBookmarksName: setBookmarkName
 updateBookmarksDescription: setBookmarkDescription
 updateBookmarksVersion: setBookmarkVersion
}

type Mutation {
 updateBookmarkFields(input: [BookmarkUpdateAction!]!): Bookmark
}
```

I do not know what this approach is called (if someone knows, please tell me! :) ) but it looks quite interesting and decent (I did not write out the whole input fields, just as I did not add the createBookmark field to the mutation - I just wanted to show the idea).

I know, that there is also an idea with so-called "mutation per attribute" but I do not know what is the point of it, and whether it will work in this case. What do you think, will this approach I presented here be good? Are there any better ones? Thanks in advance for all the answers and advice!

Comment: IMHO using separate mutations is an overkill ... input props are optional - update optionally/accept or reject/throw an exception - use some/your logic in mutation resolver

Comment: @xadm Thanks for comment. Are you talking about the "mutation per attribute" approach, or the one I showed here? Because the one I showed will have one mutation in the schema, but that mutation will contain a lot of input references.

Comment: both are creating additional complexity, problematic at scale

Comment: That's true, but I would like to avoid a situation where some arguments are required/"not null" and I don't want to change those (when I want to edit something inline).

Comment: again, custom logic/validation in resolver can do that - request/response (resolver) is more important/specific than type/schema (server input validation)